# JDialog not centered

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I tried to  center my dialog (i am using java 1.3) but it does not seem to work.
i tried all below ways..

```
dialog.setSize(100, 100);
dialog.setResizable(true);

dialog.setLocation(150, 250);
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(dialog.getParent());
```

the size of the dialog does not change when i change values in setSize method.
The location does not change when i change values in setLocation method.
It is very old code so i am not much sure what to do or how to get it workign..

Comment: Does your dialog have a parent? Is the parent visible?

Comment: first you setting hardcode location and afterwards you setting it as relative to parent, it doesnt make sense.

Comment: @icza i dont think it has a parent since it is created by `new IDialog(null, "title", true);`

Comment: @smajlo i tried both by commenting one at a time just to check...

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Probable duplicate of [Center `JDialog` over parent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10030947/418556).

Comment: I just realized you wrote you use Java 1.3. `setLocationRelativeTo()` was added in Java 1.4. If you don't get a compile error, you are not using Java 1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should build the content of the dialog, and only bother sizing it and setting its location after that.

Best would be to use proper layout managers, and once you added all your components (content) to it, simply call its `pack()` method to have the layout managers compute the size.

After that you can simply center it by calling:

```
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Passing `null` means to center it on the screen. Quoting from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo-java.awt.Component-):

> If the component is `null`, or the `GraphicsConfiguration` associated with this component is `null`, the window is placed in the center of the screen. The center point can be obtained with the `GraphicsEnvironment.getCenterPoint` method.

Although if it has a parent, `dialog.getParent()` should be passed just as you did which also works if it has no parent (`null`).