# How do I create a new JFrame, whos' location is set to the middle of another JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm new to Java and this is what I'm trying to do:

I have `frame1`, which has a `JButton` that, once clicked, creates a new `JFrame` on top of `frame1`, which I call `frame2`. I basically want `frame2` to be created in the middle of `frame1`. How do I do this?

Comment: include your relevant code

Comment: You create it the same way you created number 1, just give it a smaller dimension.

Comment: yes but then it just appears on the top-left of the screen by default. I want it on top of the first frame. Does it have something to do with setLocationRelativeTo(...)?

Comment: As a general rule, it's bad practice to throw a bunch Frames at the user. If this is just for practice, it doesn't matter too much, but I would recommend finding a better way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 3):

You set the location of frame2 relative to the location of frame1.

```
//Initialize your frames
frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(frame1);
```

This should place frame2 right on top of frame1.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is Marv's, but if you want to do it with Maths, try this instead.

```
Point offSet=frame1.getLocation();
Dimension loc1=frame1.getSize();
Dimension loc2=frame2.getSize();

double newX=offSet.getX()+loc1.getWidth()/2.0-loc2.getWidth()/2.0;
double newY=offSet.getY()+loc1.getHeight()/2.0-loc2.getHeight()/2.0;

frame2.setLocation((int)Math.floor(newX), (int)Math.floor(newY));
frame2.setVisible(true);
```

This will center `frame2` on top of `frame1`.
If you choose the `.setLocationRelativeTo()` method, don't forget to re-use `frame2.setVisible(true)` if you did `frame2.setVisible(true)` before `frame1.setVisible(true)`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setLocationRelativeTo(Component c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo(java.awt.Component)) (use [this doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo-java.awt.Component-) if you're using Java 8) as follows:

```
// center in parent
frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(frame1);
```

You can also center the component in the screen using

```
// center in screen
frame2.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
```

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030947/center-jdialog-over-parent) if you're still having issues.

Comment: Don't forget to use [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo-java.awt.Component-) if the OP uses Java 8

Comment: @Charlie I edited the post to include Java 8 doc link. Good call - thanks! (I think Marv's answer perfectly fine anyway.)